# Can not call dynamically imported python modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, plugins, import

I can not access dynamically imported modules in python.

Either my call syntax is wrong or the import does not work properly.

There are many topics on stackoverflow.com which deal with dynamic import in
Python. Yet, I adopted the code from this site: https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/238387/really-simple-plugins-loader-import-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-one-swoop

**It automagically imports all modules present in a folder and returns a dictionary.**

Code:

```
import glob, imp
from os.path import join, basename, splitext

def importPluginModulesIn(dir):
    return dict( _load(path) for path in glob.glob(join(dir,'[!_]*.py')) )
def _load(path):
    name, ext = splitext(basename(path))
    return name, imp.load_source(name, path)

modules = importPluginModulesIn('modules_folder')
print modules
```

The output suggests successful import:

```
{'test_function': <module 'test_function' from 'modules_folder/test_function.py'>}
```

**Yet, the suggested access method, yields no response at all *(should print: "Test complete.")*:**

```
modules['test_function'].__name__
```

Anyone any suggestions how to fix this?
Thanks!

EDIT:
Martijn Pieters made me aware I was actually mistaking module and function.
(See comments below.)
Now my question is how to actually, within the frame of my code, call test_function, embedded in the module
test_function.py?

EDIT2:
Content of test_function.py in modules_folder:

```
import time

def test_function():  
    print('Start.')
    time.sleep(1)    
    print('Test complete.')
```

Comment: The module is imported; why do you expect the module name to be `Test complete.`? What is *in* that module that would change the module name to something else?

Comment: 'Test complete' is the print output of test_function, not its name!

Comment: Right, but you have a **module**, not a function! And you are trying to access `__name__` of that module object, which is the module name, not any function output.

Comment: OK, I see that was inaccurate. Now how do I call test_function that is in the module test_function.py (Can a .py file be a module, or a folder with an __init__.py?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
for name in modules:
    getattr(modules[name], name)()
```

It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. But this does not work - due to: KeyError: 'test_function'. It also defies the very purpose of the dynamic import, as I do not want to hard code the import functions.

Comment: What's the content of test_function.py? After figuring out why there's a `KeyError`, try `getattr(modules['test_function'], 'test_function')()`.

Comment: Accepted, thanks  for your answer, Loquacious! I can call the function now - dynamically as requested.